# Service is not running background properly

Tags: android

My service is working the problem is while is running it's showing  a black screen until the service finish.

```
Intent Service = new Intent();
Service.setClass(Activity.this,sendInformation.class);
Service.putExtra("IP",IP1); 
Service.putExtra("Port",Port1);
Activity.this.startService(Service);
```

how i can say "while service is running" back to home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your server happens on the main thread. Try using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead or try spanning your own thread from your server's onStartCommand. Usually IntentService is fine.

Answer (score 1):

[From the `Service` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such
>   as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to
>   do that work.

Just create an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you want multithreading.